# POST request to ExpressJS route works locally, but returns HTTP 405 error in production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, amazon-s3, axios

In my React app I sending requests to my backend node / express app using axios. In my local environment, everything works well when I call it using a function that looks like this:

`await axios.post('/createproduct', createProductBody).then(res => console.log('Data send')).catch(err => console.log(err.data))`

However, this after I push my code to production, this line of code returns a status code 405 (see screenshot)

Could it be because I have added the `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"` line in my `package.json`file? I don't quite understand why this would work in `locally` but not in `prod`.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: There are many questions here, did you deploy them on the same domain? How did you deploy your express app? It says 405, which means method not supported. Did you make sure that your express app should receive post request? If it works locally. that means that the same route does not exist at the same domain in prod, then something must be wrong with the deployment

Comment: I searched for HTTP code 405 and I think it has something to do with your hosting.

Comment: Hi, yes I am deploying them on the same domain.

Comment: Not entirely sure how I deployed it, but I followed this tutorial very closely, if that offers any hints

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-react-app-with-a-node-backend-the-complete-guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the output of the below, your AWS S3 bucket is not configured to allow `POST`:

```
axios = require('axios')

function createProductBody() {
    return {}
}
async function stackOverflowQuestionNumber67929785() {
    await axios.post('https://editor.blankt.io/createproduct', createProductBody()).then(res => console.log('Data send')).catch(err => console.log(err))
}

stackOverflowQuestionNumber67929785();
```

Prints:

```
response: {
    status: 405,
    statusText: 'Method Not Allowed',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/xml',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      connection: 'close',
      allow: 'HEAD, DELETE, GET, PUT',
      date: 'Fri, 11 Jun 2021 00:58:55 GMT',
      server: 'AmazonS3',
      'x-cache': 'Error from cloudfront',
      via: '1.1 cf2a58a1ade01b9796df7d87fe311e64.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)'
    }
```

See the `allow` response header.